# Do I have a memory leak in my lua code? (lua tables)

Tags: lua

Here's a sample of what my code is:

```
listOfPeople = {}
listOfPeople["test"] = "hello"
listOfPeople = nil
```

is the "hello" string getting lost and forming a memory leak?

Thanks

Comment: Lua uses a Garbage Collector so no, unless the implementation of lua itself leaks, you don't leak memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this should not cause a leak (assuming no bugs in the Lua interpreter), but the memory is not released until the garbage collector runs its (full) cycle. You can see the effect with the following script:

```
collectgarbage()
print(collectgarbage("count"))
listOfPeople = {}
listOfPeople["test"] = "hello"
print(collectgarbage("count"))
listOfPeople = nil
collectgarbage()
print(collectgarbage("count"))
```

This prints the following using Lua 5.2:

```
14.5107421875   523
14.6533203125   669
14.5107421875   523
```

As you can see, the memory used by the interpreter is increased (for the table and two strings stored in it) and then goes back when the memory used for those elements is garbage collected.

Comment: Actually, since `"test"` and `"hello"` are literal strings, they aren't collected until the enclosing function's prototype gets collected.